# seekTo youtube Api Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Hi i have a problem with youtube Api seekTo function I'm working with youtube api where i use UIWebview to play videos and that kind of stuff however when   I try to seek forward by using a UISlider it doesn't quite work.

I can play and pause video by the following commands

```
VideoWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "ytplayer.pauseVideo()")

VideoWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "ytplayer.playVideo()")
```

however when i try to seek forward by the following command

```
VideoWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "ytplayer.seekTo(seconds:120, allowSeekAhead:false)")
```

I'm using the function only when the video is playing because i have access to the video state by using another command

```
VideoWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "ytplayer.getPlayerState()")
```

by getting the state of video i can be sure that the video is playing and i'm using the command only when the video is playing as the Youtube Api description tells me, all help is very appreciated

Comment: You can change the line `allowSeekAhead:false` to `allowSeekAhead:true` based on this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43236189/5995040) this will enable your app to seek ahead since your original code prevented it to seek. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah that was the solution I tried it yesterday and it worked fine, but thanks anyway